# Where do Eloqent Laravel Não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho o seguinte código

```
public function getConsultaLocacao() 
{           

    $consulta =  LocacaoBanco::where('id',4)->get();

    foreach($consulta as $v) 
    {       
        echo"aqui->".$v->datalocacao;
    }
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($v->datalocacao);
}
```

RESULTADO DO CODIGO

```
aqui->2019-01-01 00:00:00
string(19)"2019-01-01 00:00:00"
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora olhem meu banco de dados, o `id = 4` se refere a outra linha e o `laravel` só me retorna a errada.

```
id    datalocacao            datadevolucao          valorlocacao    estadodevolucao
4     2019-01-31 00:00:00    2019-01-31 00:00:00    11              nao
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código completo do model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LocacaoBanco extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'locacao';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $datalocacao;
    public $datadevolucao;
    public $valorlocacao;
    public $estadodevolucao;
    public $id;

        public function __construct() {

            $this->datalocacao = "2019-01-01 00:00:00";
            $this->datadevolucao = "2019-01-01 00:00:00";
            $this->valorlocacao = 5.20;
            $this->estadodevolucao = "nao";
            $this->id = null;


        }
        public function setRegLocacao() {
                $datalocacao = $this->datalocacao;
                $datadevolucao = $this->datadevolucao;
                $valorlocacao = $this->valorlocacao;
                $estadodevolucao = $this->estadodevolucao;
                $id = $this->id;

            echo "Insercao da tabela locacao executada";

        }
        public function setAtualizaLocacao() {

                $datalocacao = $this->datalocacao;
                $datadevolucao = $this->datadevolucao;
                $valorlocacao = $this->valorlocacao;
                $estadodevolucao = $this->estadodevolucao;
                $id = $this->id;
                DB::update("update locacao SET datalocacao = ?,datadevolucao = ?,valorlocacao=?,estadodevolucao=?,id=? ",[$datalocacao,$datadevolucao,$valorlocacao,$estadodevolucao,$id]);
                echo "locacao atualizada";
        }
        public function getConsultaLocacao() {


        $consulta =  LocacaoBanco::where('id',4)->get();

        foreach($consulta as $v) {

            echo"aqui->".$v->datalocacao;


        }
        echo "<br>";
            var_dump($v->datalocacao);

        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ola @Lorena, me faz um favor após a linha do `$consulta =  LocacaoBanco::where('id',4)->get();` coloque isso aqui `dd($consulta);` e me fale o resultado.

Comment: Se está fazendo errado, está usando errado o Eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

Ele não está pegando errado. Está pegando exatamente oque está no `__construct`

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->datalocacao = "2019-01-01 00:00:00";
    $this->datadevolucao = "2019-01-01 00:00:00";
    $this->valorlocacao = 5.20;
    $this->estadodevolucao = "nao";
    $this->id = null;
}
```

Você não deve ter um construtor em um Model. Tente deixar da seguinte maneira, seguindo oque está na própria [documentação do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent)

```
class LocacaoBanco extends Model {
    protected $table = 'locacao';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
            'datalocacao', 'datadevolucao', 'valorlocacao', 'estadodevolucao'
        ];
}
```

Para realizer os testes, você pode utilizar o tinker do Laravel, não coloque o código no seu Model que não seja estritamente de responsabilidade dele.

Para realizar inserções na sua tabela, utilize LocacaoBanco::create. Ex.:

```
LocacaoBanco::create([
    'datalocacao' => '2019-01-31 00:00:00', 
    'datadevolucao' => '2019-01-31 00:00:00',
    'valorlocacao' => '11',
    'estadodevolucao' => 'nao'
])
```

E para realizar consultas, utilize o where normalmente, da forma como você utilizou. 
Realize os testes no terminal utilizando o tinker `php artisan tinker`. Depois:

```
use App\LocacaoBanco

$model= LocacaoBanco::find(4)

$model->datalocacao
```

Segue aqui também, um [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zR-LWfv1tmY) onde você pode aprender a utilizar melhor o tinker.